# Year 2015 Stats for SFSE

Tags: discussion

I've looked at some of the statistics for SFSE contributions for this year (based on whatever normal members can see) and it looks like it has been an amazing year for our community as a whole. Can the moderators publish some stats at the end of this month in terms of

- Count of New members added through the year (YoY growth)
- Ratio of questions answered/ posted
- Top Questions & answers for the year
- Number of badges given out through the year
- Overall edits, flags count for the year

P.S. - It's a good time to reflect on the year gone by. For those interested in reading, I took some time to [reflect on my year 2015](https://gauravkheterpal.wordpress.com/2015/12/23/2015-my-salesforce-year-in-review/) as a member of the Salesforce developer community

Comment: We'll have to look into this in regards to what we have and what can be made public.  To start: the winter bash leaderboard: http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: Haha still clinging to my lead in hats!

Comment: I'm coming for you Adrian...haha   jk

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I decided to dig into the database a bit to get a few more stats as requested and because I was also curious.

**New Users By Year:**

```
+------+-----------+
| Year | New Users |
+------+-----------+
| 2015 |      8357 |
| 2014 |      5359 |
| 2013 |      2260 |
| 2012 |       943 |
+------+-----------+
```

**New Users in 2015 By Month**

```
+---------+-----------+
|  Month  | New Users |
+---------+-----------+
| 2015-12 |       660 |
| 2015-11 |       734 |
| 2015-10 |       873 |
| 2015-09 |       764 |
| 2015-08 |       733 |
| 2015-07 |       797 |
| 2015-06 |       784 |
| 2015-05 |       620 |
| 2015-04 |       586 |
| 2015-03 |       702 |
| 2015-02 |       570 |
| 2015-01 |       534 |
+---------+-----------+
```

**Question/Answer Stats:**

For 2015, there have been **16,050 questions asked** that haven't been deleted.  Of these, **11,996 have at least one answer**.

**Top 10 Questions Asked in 2015 by Score**

- [Apex debugging in Winter '16 - how well does it work?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94881)
- [Salesforce, Oracle and the Seven Dwarfs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423)
- [How can I tell what is changing in Salesforce as they patch each pod?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80546)
- [What is the difference between Custom Settings and Custom Metadata Types](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74049)
- [What causes a Connected App's Refresh Token to expire?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65590)
- [Which kind of issues will be shown at trust.salesforce.com and which issues will be omited?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80769)
- [How to write the superduper (=proper and stable) Custom Save method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71509)
- [Requirescript change in Winter '16 release](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92462)
- [Force.com IDE Debugger. New feature?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74003)
- [How to build custom UI that works both for users that have opted in to Lightning Experience and users that have not?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96220)

**Top 10 Answers Posted in 2015 By Score**

- [What is the difference between Custom Settings and Custom Metadata Types](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74139)
- [What are the object and field name suffixes that Salesforce uses? Such as __c and __x](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101845)
- [(Why) Should I Use Lightning Apps?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67809)
- [Apex debugging in Winter '16 - how well does it work?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94922)
- [Force.com IDE Debugger. New feature?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74016)
- [Controlling Trigger Execution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71403)
- [How to handle an HTTP response time beyond two minutes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74272)
- [Salesforce, Oracle and the Seven Dwarfs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76779)
- [What is a use case where one would use an SObject as a Map key?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71436)
- [How Many Starttest() and StopTest() can I have in One Test Class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66388)

**Top Badges Awarded in 2015`*`**

```
+------------------+-------------------------+
|      Badge       | Number Of Times Awarded |
+------------------+-------------------------+
| Student          |                    2683 |
| Informed         |                    1596 |
| Editor           |                    1566 |
| Scholar          |                    1539 |
| Autobiographer   |                    1493 |
| Supporter        |                    1247 |
| Popular Question |                    1167 |
| Teacher          |                    1115 |
| Tumbleweed       |                     955 |
| Notable Question |                     617 |
| Commentator      |                     604 |
| Yearling         |                     593 |
| Custodian        |                     373 |
| Curious          |                     336 |
| Critic           |                     239 |
| Nice Question    |                     183 |
| Revival          |                     157 |
| Citizen Patrol   |                     139 |
| Nice Answer      |                     124 |
+------------------+-------------------------+
```

`*` This only includes badges awarded more than 100 times.

**Edit Stats**

There were a total of **17,349 edits** performed this year.  I limited the total to the title and body edits, leaving out trivial tag edits.

**Flag Stats for the Year**

```
+-------------+-----------+------------------------+---------------+
| Total Flags | Mod Flags | Spam & Offensive Flags | Comment Flags |
+-------------+-----------+------------------------+---------------+
|        2813 |      2484 |                    210 |           119 |
+-------------+-----------+------------------------+---------------+
```

Mod Flags include Not An Answer, Other, and Low Quality flags.

Comment: Those are pretty awesome stats. Thanks for sharing!!

Comment: @NormalHuman I'm putting it to [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272040/should-we-create-a-year-in-review) to offer suggestions about what sites would want for annual stats.  Good idea.

Comment: Hoping this triggers the change for for all sites to transition from the retired evaluations to these queries. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 8):

There is the [Site Analytics privilege](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) at 25,000 rep. Those with access can see it at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/site-analytics.

Here are the weekly stats for the year to date for two of the available areas.

## Posts

[image]

## Votes

[image]

---

There is also the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/queries). With that you could probably find the exact answers you are looking for.

I came across the existing [Yearly stats query](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/419383/yearly-stats?year=2015&opt.textResults=true) that has some further interesting stats.

```
year questions answers 
---- --------- ------- 
2012 1559      2863    
2013 5823      8227    
2014 12004     15095   
2015 16131     17805   
2016 352       393    

year accepts upvotes downvotes 
---- ------- ------- --------- 
2012 1033    11099   443       
2013 2888    37833   1508      
2014 5360    55480   3323      
2015 6264    51715   4942      
2016 155     1509    98   

year comments 
---- -------- 
2012 6174     
2013 20136    
2014 37318    
2015 46732    
2016 1280  

year Edits 
---- ----- 
2012 1933  
2013 6365  
2014 12217 
2015 14467 
2016 475  

year total_questions total_answers 
---- --------------- ------------- 
2012 1637            3113          
2013 6280            9012          
2014 13918           16800         
2015 18285           20149         
2016 367             447
```

Comment: Daniel - thank you for sharing the stats. The Data Explorer and the charts are handy and provide a good overview for what I was looking for. As for the Site Analytics privileges (25K points), I'm not there yet but I'll definitely make sure I get there soon enough so I can look at the next year 2016 stats! Cheers!

Comment: Awesome, thank you!